# How to make a circle only appear in certain divs with different colours?

Tags: html, css

Basically I will try to keep this simple.

I am trying to do something like this (ignore any design aspects except what I state):

[image: Image link.]

I have started this on JSFiddle [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/od62shsp/1/)

```css
.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.header {
  background-color: #0091cc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.circle {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
</div>

<div class="circle"></div>
```

Basically the problem is I cannot make it appear that the circle connects through the two rectangles and have two different colours, like in the image. While still cutting out the rest of the circle, that spills out of the rectangle.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for colour,  you can use opacity: 0.5; check this: https://jsfiddle.net/maky/od62shsp/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to change your mark up. In order to get the old mark up to work, it would have been too hacky. Basically I assigned a circle for each header, and I set overflow to hidden on the header. Then I play with the top property to decide which part of the circle I want to display. There is slight blue showing up on the border to the left, but I'm sure it won't take long to figure out why.

```css
.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.header {
  background-color: #0091cc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.circle.top {
  top: 0;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;  
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;  
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="circle top pink"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="circle yellow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using this example as base, you can also achieve the same thing with pseudo-elements to save the extra markup. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/vjde0ars/)

Comment: @RicardoRuiz very true. Using the before pseudo element is actually better practise imo. But it wasn't included in OP's solution, and I didn't want to change too much.

Comment: You can also turn off the `overflow: hidden` until you have the `top` property just right.  That is, you can turn it off and get the circles to perfectly overlap first before cutting them off again.

Comment: @Patrick I don't think the circles can line up perfectly between the bottom and the top header, the reason being is that there's a margin in between. Or maybe I'm missing something? The way I thought about it is the top circle starts at top 0, and the bottom circle starts at top 50%, which gives the illusion that they're lined up.

Comment: @zsawaf, yeah, I'm just talking about the illusion of lining up.  It's always going to be dependent on the distance between the elements, so that has to be rigidly controlled, which makes the problem rather annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do this with even less HTML markeup and use a `::before` or `::after` psuedo-element to create the circle: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

This creates a child element for a circle in each header and setting `overflow:hidden` on the header conceals the parts of the circle you don't want to be visible.

```css
.header-wrapper {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background-color: #0091cc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}

.header::after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  height: 400px;
  left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
}

.header:nth-child(1)::after {
  background-color: pink;
  top: -100px;
}

.header:nth-child(2)::after {
  background-color: orange;
  bottom: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/od62shsp/4/